# My C# app coded for WP7 will not launch properly on WP8 phone with deployment

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, compatibility, windows-phone-8

So, I have created a (C#) WP7 app that doesn't have too much complicated things in it. A webbrowser control, IsolatedStorageSettings, and some other basic stuff. When I tested this app on one of my WP7 devices, it works perfectly. Debugging works fine. Deploying also works fine. The app is acting completely normal.

When I then got hold of a Nokia Lumia 822, I developer unlocked the device. I deployed the WP7 version of the XAP file, and then tried it. First launch, it works perfectly! Then, I completely exit the app with the back button. I try opening it again, and what happened? It doesn't even show the splash screen. I try launching it a few more times, doesn't work.

I restarted my WP8 device. I then started up my app again, and it worked. I did what I did last time, exit out of the app and then restart it. The issue comes up again, no splash screen.

After I was frustrated enough, I fired up Visual Studio 2012. I connected my WP8, and then debugged it. Works fine! I exit the app on the device using the back button, and Visual Studio still thinks the app is running. I then restart the app from the device, and it works again! I tried that again, and it still worked. Whenever the app isn't in debugging mode, it crashes. Whenever the app is in debugging mode, it works.

Here is a video of what's happening: http://youtu.be/3zKFxj98liY

Anyone have a solution to this?

Comment: Not a solution, but what you need to do is get a copy of the Phone 8 SDK and test your app **in release mode** in the Phone 7.1 and Phone 8 emulators. I've seen a few things that aren't consistent between the Phone 8 and Phone 7. In most cases it's very simple, but still could require a code change

Comment: Looking at the animation, doesn't seem the app is getting closed, but rather going to the background... have you tryed hitting the hardware Back button when that happened?

Comment: When I said that I tried Visual Studio 2012, I had SDK 8. I first tested the app in release mode when the app was still optimized for 7.1, but then I converted the solution to a WP8 app and tried again. Just like it says up there, works fine when the app is running through the USB cable. It just doesn't work when the XAP is deployed to the phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haha, I just found out the reason! Clipboard.SetText is not supported on WP8 anymore and it crashes the app.